# OpenShift Java application connection to external Amazon RDS Database

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, openshift

Amazon RDS Databases require that I supply the IP address of any machine that should be permitted to make connections.  In my local Apache Tomcat development server, my Java application is able to connect to my Amazon RDS database, and I had to supply my computer's IP address to allow this connection.

Fast forward to deploying my application to OpenShift.  My application is deployed successfully and I can get to my log in page.  I created a test page on the application to output the OpenShift server IP address on which my application is running.  I added that IP address to the security protocol on Amazon RDS just like I did for my local machine.  However, the deployed application on Openshift is still not successfully making a connection to my Amazon RDS database.

I'm using the free OpenShift account.  I'm wondering if the free account version doesn't permit external database connections?  Or, am I not capturing the correct IP address of the OpenShift server where my application is stored?

Comment: Did you create Security Groups with the IP range?  Check this if you havent https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-use-amazon-rds-with-your-openshift-application/

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can conduct an experiment:

- Create a small function in your application - to fetch some URL at another server you have control over, that is you can read its access.log and it accepts connections from any IP.
- Then run this function (by accessing your test page, using remote shell, or by scheduling a cron job).
- And check the access.log.

So you will determinate IP address (if it is changed by some kind of proxy).
If nothing is logged, then it seems external connections are blocked.

---

You need to determinate IP address of openstack's Web Proxy. 
See about Web Proxy and ports 8000, 8443 at https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html

If there are many such IPs, you can create SSH tunnel and forward one port, so your connection to the database will be local.